# how to change query of view and add union itself in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, view, unions

1. I have a table that have 2 types of data first type is '1' second type is '2'
   and i want to get 3 records of both by union so, i want to know that how 
   to get 3 records of both type from one table at a time so it is possible by 
   union with itself so i want to add 
   union with my views content so , how to get query of view and alter it and
   where i put this query in drupal 7 but i have no one module for this data.

   so, please help me how to get records and change query

Answer (score 1):

You can use Views extra handlers module to union SQL queries of two different views/displays. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_extra_handlers 
[image: screenshot of union settings]